# Why can't add tags into terraform modules

Tags: postgresql, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-database-postgresql

I got some problem to provision with tags on **Azure** database for PostgreSQL services, My code be like

```
module "postgresql" {
  source = "./modules/postgresql"
  service               = var.service
  .
  .
  .
  tags = { test = "test" }
```

And error happend

```
53:  tags = {

An argument named "tags" is not expected here.
```

Why always happened like this, Actually in the Resource_Group module has tags but It doesn't error at all
, I'm kinda confused about this Does anyone knows about this please help me and Thank you for your kind help

Comment: Does the module expose a tags variable? You haven't posted your module source so this isn't really answerable as is.

Comment: Oh man, it was so embarrassing I forgot about vars, I thought it was about version, Thanks

Comment: If you solve the issue, please add an answer to display the solution to help other communities, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As the error stated: "An argument named "tags" is not expected here.", you should define the variable `tags` in your child module when you're [calling a child module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#calling-a-child-module) because most of the arguments correspond to [input variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) defined by the module. Alternatively, if the resources does not support [tags](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/resource_group.html#tags) arguments, you can not use `tags` under that resource.

For example, you will have input variable `tags` in your modules configuration file if the resources support `tags`.

```
variable "tags" {

}
...

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "myterraformnetwork" {
  name                = var.vnetname
  address_space       = var.address_space
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rgname
  tags = var.tags
}
```