# Terraform AWS ..An argument named "tags" is not expected here

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I can write bit terraform and ignored modules at first. Now I am trying to learn them, but it's not going well.

Here is my module code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
  ami           = var.ami
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  tags = {
    "Name" = var.instance_name
  }
}
```

Here is my `variables.tf` file:

```
variable "instance_name" {
  description = "Name of the EC2 instance"
}

variable "instance_type" {
  description = "Type of the EC2 instance"
}

variable "ami" {
  description = "amiid"
}
```

I am calling this like below:

```
module "prod" {
  source        = "./modules/ec2-instance"
  ami           = "ami-08a52ddb321b32a8c"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  instance_name = "hellll"
  tags = {
    Name = "helloo"
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> Error: Unsupported argument
> │
> on ec2module.tf line 7, in module "prod":
> 7:   tags = {
> │
> An argument named "tags" is not expected here.

I don't understand why I am getting this error. The same tags works in just AWS_instance resource

```
resource "aws_instance" "name" {
  ami = "ami-08a52ddb321b32a8c"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  tags = {
    "Name" = "dev"
  }
}
```

But why is this not working in a module, am I missing some thing? Based on this answer, I have even exposed this tag in module: [Why can't add tags into terraform modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934062/why-cant-add-tags-into-terraform-modules)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `variables.tf` for the module, you are missing `tags` variable. You have to add:

```
variable "tags" {
  description = "Tags for the instance"
}
```

Otherwise you can't pass it them into the module, the way you are trying to do now.

Comment: I think we need to add `type = map` too, right?

Comment: @Ikigaiprogrammeh Up to you. You can add `type = map`

Comment: i misunderstand how these variables work..apparaently you can add anything like `variable "tagg" {
  description = "tags "
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    "name" = "nulll"
  }
  
}` and then tou can call in main like ` tagg = {
    Name ="web"
  }
 `....Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues here.

The first issue is as Marcin mentioned, you forgot to declare the variable tags. However the way you've written your module, you're statically defining tags as `name = var.instance_name`

Therefore, your two options are:

1. Remove the `tags` argument from `module.prod` as it's not actually being used
2. Change your `ec2_instance` resource to accept something like `tags = var.tags` instead of `name = var.instance_name`